# Selecting columns that have values in Excel Macro (range object in VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

How do I modify this line in VBA to only select the columns that have values?

```
Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

I don't think I'm doing something right since the `CountLarge` property is several billion cells

Here is a sample of my data

[image]

Comment: I assume you mean  VBA (run from Excel) rather than a vbscript?

Comment: Lastly, if you want cells with values in then you need to be using SpecialCells with xlConstants and/or XlFormulas. Your current code looks for visible cells, rather than non-empty cells. An example of how your data looks would help.

Comment: I agree  with brettdj. Plus, you might consider using `Intersect` too and/or End(xlToLeft)

Comment: `Range("A65536")` I assume that you are using Excel 2003 (Tag says 2007)? I agree with brettdj however the only problem is that there is a limit of 8192 areas that SpecialCells can handle in Excel 2003. See this link. 
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;832293. Till the time it is under that limit, you'll be good to go. Noncontiguous cells that can be selected in Excel 2010 is 2,147,483,648 cells. So if you are using Excel 2010 then if you have even less to worry about :)

Comment: By your definition, does column G have a value?  In your example, what range would be assigned to "rng"?

Comment: @DougGlancy I think part of the issue is that I'm missing header values, yes all columns have a value.

Comment: @brettdj How can I learn more about SpecialCells and the arguments for it?  I added sample data per your request. Yes VBA not VBScript

Comment: @SiddharthRout What is the correct Range value to use for Excel 2007/10?  Thanks for the special cells info.  I'm still figuring out how to apply it to my situation

Comment: @makerofthings7: I am not sure what do you mean by `What is the correct Range value to use for Excel 2007/10?` also regarding `I'm still figuring out how to apply it to my situation`, since brettdj gave that suggestion first (which is the right way), I would suggest you to wait till he posts a reply :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout if `Range(A65536)` is for Excel 2003, what is needed for other versions?

Comment: @makerofthings7: The correct way is to use `Rows.Count` for all Excel Versions instead of hardcoding the numbers. For example `Range(A65536)` can be written as `Range("A" & Rows.Count)`, which will work for all excel versions :)

Comment: So, in this example you want to set rng to range("A:L")?  The entire column?  Again, in this example, what address would rng be set to?

Comment: @Doug: I believe in such a case the right approach would be to use `Cells.SpecialCells()` instead of hardcoding the columns (which I suspect even brettdj might go in for when presenting his solution)

Comment: @makerofthings7: just for clarification, it's not the columns you are selecting as you mentioned in the title but all the cells which have data?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I'm not suggesting hardcoding. I'm trying to understand what makerofthings7 wants, and knowing what would be returned in this specific example would help me.

Comment: @DougGlancy - This is the data of a CSV file that has no headers.  I need to filter it using VBA using AutoFilter and get the row that has the data, and process it.  The CSV is a temp file that is exported to a different sheet, line by line.  The data is being transformed in the process.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes I only need the rows that have data.  I think I have it working now with End(xlToLeft) from @JMax ... Now that I'm iterating over the cells, I can just quit the `For each` loop once the last row is reached.  I *might* have this working now.

Comment: @makerofthings7: I think I know what exactly you are trying to do :) you don't need to use loops to achieve what you want. Just a quick question. Is it possible that say Cell C10 might have a value but B10 might not?

Comment: @SiddharthRout All cells should have a value. I don't think it's possible for a blank value, but maybe it's OK. I'm still in the design phase

Comment: @makerofthings7: I already submitted an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > > @SiddharthRout Yes I only need the rows that have data. I think I have it working now with End(xlToLeft) from @JMax ... Now that I'm iterating over the cells, I can just quit the For each loop once the last row is reached. I might have this working now. – makerofthings7 14 mins ago

For this neither you need `.SpecialCells` nor do you need to loop through the rows :)

Here is a sample code. This will copy all the rows which have data to Sheet2 (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

        LastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Column

        With .Range("A1:" & Split(Cells(, LastCol).Address, "$")(1) & LastRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
            Set rng = ws.AutoFilter.Range
            rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

I am assuming that all cells in a particular row will have data and there won't be a case like this

> > > @makerofthings7: I think I know what exactly you are trying to do :) you don't need to use loops to achieve what you want. Just a quick question. Is it possible that say Cell C10 might have a value but B10 might not? – Siddharth Rout 12 mins ago

If there is then we will have to set the autofilter criteria accordingly.

**Edit:**
**WAY 2**

The other way would be to sort your data, pushing the blanks way down and then copying the resulting range :)

HTH