# Excel Vba - Copy row if value in cell is greater than

Tags: excel, vba

I've got this table full of data. And column K in each row contains a number. So basically what I'm trying to do is move that entire row, if the data in that column is greater than 9, over to sheet2.

How can this be achieved? I've already created actual tables in the sheets, called Table1 and Table2.

This is what I've managed to put together so far. I've looked at autofilter, but I can't understand squat of what's happening in there. So this I get!

```
Sub MoveData()

    Dim i As Range
    Dim num As Integer
     num = 1
    For Each i In Range("K10:K1000")
        If i.Value > 9 Then
            i.Select
            ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Copy

            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(num, 0).PasteSpecial
            ActiveCell.Rows.Delete
            num = num + 1

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This kinda works so far. But I can't manage to paste the row to the next blank row in sheet2. I tried doing that num = num + 1 thing, but I guess that's way off?

Comment: It's easy. What have you tried till now? If you haven't tried anything then you might want to look at `.Autofilter` and then moving the filtered rows using `.Offset()` ?

Comment: And here is what I mean :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050946/selecting-columns-that-have-values-in-excel-macro-range-object-in-vba If you are still stuck then post back the code that you tried and we will take it form there :)

Comment: I looked at that code and I don't get what's going on. I've tried editing it, but I get this error "AutoFilter method of Range class failed" at the line ".AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"". Now, the stuff I've put together above is probably the hard way of doing it.

Comment: No worries, I will give you an example soon. Can you please confirm the following? Your table is from Range("K10:K1000") and you want to paste in sheet2's next blank row? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct :) I just want to search column K for any number above 9. And if it is, copy that entire row into a new blank row in Sheet2.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying? (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim rRange As Range

    Dim lastRowWsO As Long

    Set wsI = Sheets("sheet1")

    '~~> Assuming that the Header is in K10
    Set rRange = wsI.Range("K10:K1000")

    Set wsO = Sheets("sheet2")

    '~~> Get next empty cell in Sheet2
    lastRowWsO = wsO.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With wsI
        '~~> Remove Auto Filter if any
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With rRange
            '~~> Set the Filter
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=9"

            '~~> Temporarirly hide the unwanted rows
            wsI.Rows("1:9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            wsI.Rows("1001:" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.Hidden = True

            '~~> Copy the Filtered rows
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            wsO.Rows(lastRowWsO)

            '~~> Delete The filtered rows
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        '~~> Unhide the rows
        .Rows("1:9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Rows("1001:" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.Hidden = False

        '~~> Remove Auto Filter
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**NOTE**: I have not included any error handling. I would recommend you to include one in the final code

**FOLLOWUP**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim rRange As Range

    Dim lastRowWsI As Long, lastRowWsO As Long

    Set wsI = Sheets("Risikoanalyse")

    '~~> Assuming that the Header is in K10
    Set rRange = wsI.Range("K9:K1000")

    lastRowWsI = wsI.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=wsI.Range("A1"), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row


    Set wsO = Sheets("SJA utarbeides")

    '~~> Get next empty cell in Sheet2
    lastRowWsO = wsO.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=wsO.Range("A1"), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row + 1

    With wsI
        With .ListObjects("TableRisikoAnalyse")
            '~~> Set the Filter
            .Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=">=9"

            '~~> Temporarirly hide the unwanted rows
            wsI.Rows("1:8").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            wsI.Rows(lastRowWsI & ":" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.Hidden = True

            '~~> Copy the Filtered rows
            wsI.Range(Replace(wsI.Range("K9").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address, "$9:$9,", "")).EntireRow.Copy _
            wsO.Rows(lastRowWsO)

            '~~> Clear The filtered rows
            wsI.Range(Replace(wsI.Range("K9").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address, "$9:$9,", "")).Clear

            .Range.AutoFilter Field:=11

            '~~> Sort the table so that blank cells are pushed down                
            .Sort.SortFields.Clear
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("TableRisikoAnalyse[[ ]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
            :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
            With .Sort
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
        End With

        '~~> Unhide the rows
        .Rows("1:8").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Rows(lastRowWsI & ":" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.Hidden = False

        '~~> Remove Auto Filter
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I still get that 1004 error. AutoFilter method of Range class failed on the line .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=9".

Comment: May I see a sample of your file for a faster resolution? If yes, then you may upload it in wikisend.com and share the link here

Comment: Here:
http://wikisend.com/download/195882/Risikovurdering Analyse JV 12 - ferdig (1).xlsm

Comment: Unable to open the file. says extension is not valid.

Comment: Yeah, copy the whole line, instead of just clicking the link.

Comment: Ok checked it. We will have to alter the code as we are working with `tables`. not sure how I missed that :) Will look at the file and update the code shortly.

Comment: Ok I am done. Could you please confirm in which order is your table sorted? I mean which column?

Comment: It's the value in column K. If the value in that cell on that particular row is above 9, move that entire row to sheet2. As you can see, I've added conditional formatting. So if the value in column K is 10 or more, that row is colored red. That same row should be moved to sheet2 when the macro is run. As well as all the other ones that that might be colored red

Comment: I understand that. That has been taken care of. I just want to check your table is sorted in which order?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You mean filtering? Like, sorting the values from high to low? No sorting is turned on normally, because each line has an ID on them. In column C. So I guess it's sorted by low to high based on column C.

Comment: `Col C` That is what I was looking for :)